# How to merge two ranges into a named range using Google Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have two ranges in different sheets.

I would like to create a named range merging these ranges.

In a nutshell, there are two ranges:

```
Sheet1!A2:A1000

Sheet2!A2:A1000
```

I need a named range with these ranges together as `{Sheet1!A2:A1000; Sheet2!A2:A1000}`

Comment: Hey could you give an example of the current input and expected output?

Comment: I don't think it is possible to have a NamedRange containing cells from differernt sheets.  And I'm not sure what you intend to do with it because a VLOOKUP or similar function wouldn't know which sheet to get the value from.   You could have on Sheet1 column A and in column B a formula `=Sheet2!A1`.  Then a named range for Sheet1!A:B

Answer (score 0):

According to the Google Apps Script documentation the way to set a named range is by using the Google Sheets API integration with the [NamedRange class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/named-range#setRange(Range)), and the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/concepts) of the Google Sheets API shows the correct formatting to use and some range samples you can use.

The documentation only shows examples related to ranges from a single sheet, so in this case it would not be possible to set a single named range for ranges in 2 different sheets.